# Issue with UIPickerView in didSelectRow

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi have 4 component in my `UIPickerView`

When i am calling `didSelectRow` in `UIPickerView`.

When I am Rolling `selectedRowInComponent:1`

I am displaying `NSLog(@"hours");`

When I am Rolling  `selectedRowInComponent:0`

I am displaying `NSLog(@"date");`

when i am scrolling `selectedRowInComponent:1`

It still display me date ... Not hours.

@any one help me out

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    //get the values
    NSInteger date_NewRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSInteger hour_NewRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSInteger minute_NewRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:2];
    NSInteger am_pm_NewRow = [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:3];

    if (date_NewRow) {
        NSLog(@"date");
    }
    else if (hour_NewRow) {
        NSLog(@"hours");
    }


    //some code to save the values 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the if else condition?

Comment: You can log the integer values like NSLog (@"Hours %i",hour_NewRow );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you might be checking the wrong values. If you want to know which component changed, check the component variable:

```
if      (component==0) NSLog(@"date");
else if (component==1) NSLog(@"hour");
else if (component==2) NSLog(@"minute");
else if (component==3) NSLog(@"am-pm");
```

Best,
Sascha